# How to connect to 3 devices on the same subnet with a network adapter card

Tags: network-adapter, subnet, gigabit-ethernet, ubuntu-20.04

I have assembled 1 PC with Ubuntu version 20.04.3.LTS.
That PC needs to be used to connect to 3 cameras which are sending their data via an ethernet connection using TCP protocol for configuration and UDP for image streaming.
So I equipped the PC with an ethernet network card ([Link to the product](https://www.startech.com/en-be/networking-io/st4000spexi)) to have additional ethernet ports.
I can configure each of them individually, 4 additional ethernet ports are visible (*enp9s0f0/1/2/3*) and they're all working perfectly individually :
[My Ubuntu Network Parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEmZJ.png)

I have 3 cameras, they all have their own IP address which is configurable :

- 192.168.0.81
- 192.168.0.88
- 192.168.0.82

(They also have specific addresses which can be set for the UDP streaming IP address or the port)

I'm trying to make 2 cameras work together as a starting point.
I have developed a program using an API to connect to those cameras and capture images which are sent via UDP protocol.
Usually I only need to set a fixed IP to the ethernet port and by indicating the correct IP addresses inside my code, the API is able to grab data from the cameras.

I noticed that if 1 camera is connected, I can make things work without issues. But when I add an additional one on the network card, it will not be possible to connect to it.

The second camera that I connect on the adapter card is always visible but it will not answer to the ping command for example. It's unreachable.

I think it might be due to the fact that the cameras are on the same network subnet but I'm not really sure about this.

It seems that it can be solved by using some network table system but I'm not familiar at all with this.

Is it possible to make this work somehow ?

Comment: I suspect that the problem is that the 3 cameras are in the same subnet. Instead of a 4port ethernet card, you could have a single port connected to a switch and the 3 cameras to that switch.

Comment: @jcbermu That could be a solution if I can't make it work. I was expecting this network card to integrate such system directly but it seems my understanding is incorrect. I guess this card is useful when connected to many switches, not ideal in my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work by configuring the cameras in the following way :

1. Camera1 : Device IP = 192.168.0.1, Streaming IP = 192.168.0.2, enp9s0f0 fixed IP = 192.168.0.2
2. Camera2 : Device IP = 192.168.1.1, Streaming IP = 192.168.1.2, enp9s0f1 fixed IP = 192.168.1.2
3. Camera 3 : Device IP = 192.168.2.1, Streaming IP = 192.168.2.2, enp9s0f2 fixed IP = 192.168.2.2

It's quite simple in the end. Key is to have them on different subnets and use the same subnet for Device and Streaming data IPs.

I do not need additional hardware with this configuration nor Bridge configuration under Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Normally each network interface is independent at layer 2 – which basically means each interface is a separate "subnet" physically. (Which is why they all have separate IP configuration!)

Trying to configure several independent interfaces with the same IP subnet number will not work as expected – only one of them will be used for *all* outbound packets to the entire subnet (whichever of the 3 identical routes in the IP routing table `ip r` ends up having lowest metric set). The host does not try to probe all interfaces to figure out which one allows reaching the IP address you want – it'll just always use the same 1st interface for everything.

There are two ways to achieve what you want (keeping everything in the same subnet), both involve the same kind of layer-2 connectivity:

- Create a virtual *bridge* interface and add all 4 physical Ethernet interfaces as "bridge ports". Only the bridge should be configured with an IP address from the subnet.
- Buy a cheap 5-port Ethernet switch, connect it to *one* of your physical Ethernet ports, and connect all cameras to that switch. Keep the other interfaces disconnected, or use them for something else (different subnets).

As your devices mainly communicate with the PC and not with each other, the 1st option (software bridge) will be good enough.

NetworkManager supports creating bridges, but the standard Ubuntu network settings app doesn't have that as an option – instead you'll need to use `nm-connection-editor` (from the network-manager-gnome package) or `nmcli con add type bridge`.

(Don't forget to disable STP in the bridge's settings; the obsolete STP version used by Linux will otherwise spend ~30 seconds learning the network state, which is annoying.)

(This method *would* still work if the devices were e.g. a PC and a NAS, which wanted to talk directly to each other, but a physical Ethernet switch would offer somewhat better performance as it doesn't rely on your CPU to do the L2 bridging.)

Comment: Thank you for the explanations. 
I've tried to bridge only one of the 4 connections using nm-connection-editor at the moment but I wasn't able to make it work. I'll try again by bridging the 4 interfaces together. 
One question though, after doing that, which address shall I use inside my code to get the images from the cameras ? Will it be possible to differentiate the flow of images depending on an IP address setting ? If there are links online about similar configurations that'd be appreciated.